# How to create own remote real hardware testing device (à la BrowserStack)

Tags: javascript, ios, remote-access, browserstack

I have an iPhone 11 with me that I would to like to be enabled to control via normal desktop browsers similar in a way to how BrowserStack (to those who are familiar with) does it. The only purpose of this iPhone would be a remote testing device. The intention then is to provide a link to my co-workers who will then be able to take turns to test their stuff on this device which is active 24x7 for remote entry.

So, in a real life scenario, I would provide a link lets say (myIphoneTest.com that I will own) to my coworkers who when they go to the url will see something exactly similar to what's on BrowserStack Live testing.

That is the basic TLDR of it. Can anyone help me with how I would go about accomplishing this. Even a simple pointing to the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: It seems you want to build your own "BrowserStack". Why not use the service? The have iPhone11 available. Is it about pricing? Or is it about some other feature of this exact phone?

Comment: I own a small startup with 30 freelance 3D Artists that we work with.  They make a type of 3D model (USDZ format. There is no known accurate USDZ viewer) that would they would need to see how it looks on an iOS device and most of them do not own iphones. 

Since setting up so many browserStack subscriptions would be non cost effective, I had this idea of using one local iOS device that our artists can then queue to use similar to browserStack but with just this specific functionality. 

It seems like it is an impossible task for a smallish company, so we are looking into other alternatives

Comment: This question is maybe best asked on superuser, the way your comment sounds like.

Comment: Maybe you could set up a phone to share it's screen onto a desktop pc, then allow each of the users a remote access to that machine?